# Cant clone the wiring Pi repository by Egit

Tags: eclipse, git, raspberry-pi, egit, wiringpi

I'm trying to build the cross compiling environment for Raspberry Pi.

I need GPIO liblary named 'wiring Pi', so I tried to clone from its repository using Egit on Eclipse(MARS).

Wirring Pi repository is here:
[git://git.drogon.net/wiringPi](http://git://git.drogon.net/wiringPi)

The cloning process apparently seemed to be successful, but the source codes were not downloaded.

The procedure was:

1. Right click on project explorer -> import
2. Select 'Project from git' -> Next
3. Input the repository URL -> Done
4. Select C Project -> Next
5. Input Project name -> Select Empty Project and toolchain -> Next
6. (I selected 'Cross GCC' for toolchainm, then I was required to input Cross GCC command here)
7. -> Done

Someone please tell me what's wrong.

Comment: could you try to clone the git repository the normal way and then import it in Eclipse?

Comment: I have already tried to clone by normal way (Atlassian SourceTree), and it went successfully. But I couldn't import them by 'Project from git'.